# Linq to Sql selecting last row in a joined table

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am trying to select multiple table values using `linq` to sql

This is the code I wrote:

```
var query = (from p in context.Personel
join y in context.PerLanguage on p.ID equals y.ID
where p.Resign == false && p.KGBT > new DateTime(2012,1,15)
select new{ p.ID,p.NameSurname, y.EarnedDate,y.Degree}).ToList();
```

PerLanguage has a foreignkey "ID" to Personel. So PerLanguage table can have 2 or more data that has the same ID. I am expecting this piece of code to return me a List of items having the "last" entered Language data of different people.

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: you should group by p.Id and select first record in group sorted by EarnedDate ascending

Comment: @Andrew ID is not unique, but I can try it by ordering y.EarnedDate I think. I will give it a try. Thnks

Comment: @Andrew I tried it but it gives some data that are not supposed to be given. `var query = (from p in context.Personel
join y in context.PerLanguage on p.ID equals y.ID
where p.Resign == false && p.KGBT > new DateTime(2012,1,15) orderby p.EarnedDate descending
select new{ p.ID,p.NameSurname, y.EarnedDate,y.Degree}).ToList();`

Comment: Ain't nobody got time fo that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following query.. basically we make the join, get the flat results, group it by id and descending sort the results within an ID and select the first record in every grouped result.

```
var results = context.Personel.Where(p => !p.Resign && p.KGBT > new 
DateTime(2012,1,15)).Join(context.PerLanguage, p => p.ID, pl => pl.ID, (p, pl) => 
new { p.ID, p.NameSurname, pl.EarnedDate, pl.Degree }).GroupBy(r => r.ID)
.Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(r => r.EarnedDate).First()).ToList();
```